# Parse text file to C++ directed graph or adjacency list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I have a text file that is similar to:

```
person: head, body
head: eyes, nose, ears, mouth
body: arm, leg
arm: elbow, hand
leg: thigh, knee, foot
```

I'm trying to represent this in either an adjacency list or a directed graph. What's the best way to do this? I can't figure out the best data structure or how to represent this in C++.

I've tried using a struct with values for the key (person, head, etc) and it's parent index, and it's children as a vector:

```
struct Node
{
    string key;
    int parentIndex;
    vector<string> children;
};
```

But this doesn't seem efficient. Any ideas?

Maybe this would be better?

```
struct {
    string key;
    Node* parent;
    vector<Node> children;
};
```

Comment: @Christophe i edited the question.

Comment: To read the file you should use a `std::ifstream`. For parsing lines don't forget that C++ is built on C - look into C's `strtok` function. For storage, consider some flavor of `std::map<[key], [container]<[key]>>`.

Comment: @Conduit is that to say that we should use map<string, vector<string>>? In order to query this structure, we want to use graph like algorithms like DFS, etc.

Comment: Your structure is in fact a tree:  every Node has one parent and potentialy several childern.  Is this what you intend to do ? Also, do I understand well that your Nodes are themselves stored in a vector (as you search by index instead of name) ?

Comment: @Christophe check the new question edits.

Comment: But it's still a tree : your Node has ony one parent, and the children are contained int he parent.  If your data structure is indeed a tree then your edit is ok.  But if you can have disconected parts, or if one part could be the "child" of several the you could have a problem.

Comment: I see one question in the title and a different question in the body. Tackling both at the same time is probably not a good idea. I recommend figuring out how you want to represent the data, then beat the parser into shape to fit the representation.

Comment: I think you should take a look at he adjacency matrix option. It can be represented as `vector<string>` listing all of the parts and `vector<vector<bool>>` that marks whether or not the body part in `vector<string>` at index X is in contact with the body part at index Y. No need for any custom classes.

Comment: Should be fine for DFS... if I want the nodes pointed to by "foo", I just use `map["foo"]` to retrieve them.

Comment: @user4581301 If OP is using adjacency lists instead of matrices, OP is probably concerned about turning an O(nodes+edges) algorithm into an O(nodes^2) one. Matrices are a fine option if the number of nodes is small, though.

Comment: @user4581301 matrixes are not feasible here as the number of children varies from 2-100ish.

Comment: I'm actually working on something similar. I'm using a `std::deque<std::deque<size_t>>` for mine (deque over vector since it doesn't need contiguous storage)... you could store the connections that structure, and then maintain a separate `std::deque<std::string>` to translate from `size_t` to `std::string` as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions that remain unanswered by your data sample: is there always one single point of entry (ex: person) ?  is it always a top down decomposition (i.e. each element has max one parent) ?  do the elements always come in the right odrer: first the top, then the down ?

If the answers to all three questions are yes, then your proposed structure is suitable:

- It's efficient enough, if always start exploration from the top.
- It'll be time consuming to find a specific node, as you've to traverse the whole structure.

There are still several points to fix:

- It'll be tricky to copy a node (because of the pointer to parents that must be changed for the copied node, as well as for its childern and children's children.
- adding elements to an array might invalidate parent poitners of all the chilren and children's children.

As you see, the optimal data structure depends not only on the content, but also on how you're going to use it.

There are plenty of iother approaches to do it, balancing performance aspects in a different manner. For example :

```
class mygraph {
    struct node {  // nodes that you read:  
       string name;  
       int id;            // index of the node in the nodes vector
       vector<int> in;    // parent(s) that can lead to this node
       vector<int> out;   // children you can go to
    };
    vector<node> nodes;    // all the nodes in arbitrary sequential order  
    map<string, int> dict; // map converting the names into ids (redundant and optional, useful for efficien search by name); 
public: 
    // members to populate the structure and to acces the nodes cleanly.   
};
```

Advantages:

- find any node by id is extremely fast, as it's only indexing an array.
- you don't need to worry about copy of structure as there are no pointers.
- due to in/out vectors, you can quickly move forward or backward from whatever node you want.
- redundant map (i.e. index and name) accelerates searching nodes by name

Inconvenience:  there's some overhead when populating the structure:  you need to convert every name into an id by verifying the name in the map and if absent create a new node in the nodes vector and insert name+new id in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Every "word" needs its own node.  So, your second struct is closer.  But, just be sure that the container type for children can grow dynamically after creating the node and contains pointers to the child nodes.

For two reasons:
(1) Suppose we added a line at the bottom of your data: `arm: wrist`.  It would need to be appended to children *after* the arm node had been created.
(2) Currently, your data file is well ordered.  But, what if we randomized the order of your data lines?  Would that still work?  Most directed graph programs handle that just fine

As you parse a line left-to-right, get the word.  Search all known nodes, looking for a match.  After the first line has been parsed, you have three nodes: person, head, body.  head and body are in the children of person [and their `parent` fields will both point to person], but their child lists are [currently] empty.  person will be the `root` node.

If you find a match, which you would on the second line for head, use the existing head node, and fill in the children.  With no match, create the node.

If the search fails and you have to create a new node, you may not have a place in the tree you're building to attach it to.  In that case, add it to a "hold" list [which is also part of the search], until more nodes come in and you can attach the hold items as children in which case you remove them from the hold list.

You may have to update the `root` node.  With the sample data, suppose we added `household: person dog` at the bottom.  The `root` node would need to be adjusted accordingly.  We'd also need a `dog:` line.  If we don't have it at the end, that's an *undefined* value and would need to be flagged.  Your node definition will need a `defined` bool to be able to flag this.

At the end, anything still in the hold list is extraneous data.  For example, if we had a `zebra:` line, there's no reference to it [and its `parent` will be null], and that will also need to be flagged.

When linking things in, a given node can only be referenced once.  So, if we add `household: arm`, this will conflict because arm is already a child of body.  Detect this by `parent` already being non-null